# How to create a new dataframe based on time filtered between two dates

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe of 3456349 rows spread over 31 days.

I need to extract the information on 1 specific day: the 8th of March

The date format is in the following format:

1st date:

```
2020-03-01 00:00:00+00:00
```

Last date:

```
2020-03-31 22:59:58+00:00
```

How would I do this? The following code does not work:

```
filtered_df = df[df['date'].isin(pd.date_range('2020-03-07', '2020-03-09'))]
```

Comment: did you try `==` yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
filtered_df = df.query("(date>'2020-03-07') & (date<'2020-03-09')")
```

Answer (score 0):

If the type of the 'date' column is DateTimeIndex you only need to try this code:

```
df.loc['2020-03-01 00:00:00+00:00':'2020-03-31 22:59:58+00:00']
```

If not, you can try this:

```
mask = (df['date'] > '2020-03-01 00:00:00+00:00') & (df['date'] <= '2020-03-31 22:59:58+00:00')

df.loc[mask]
```